# Joint distribution - question on limits - find $$ so that $(,)=$ will be a joint density, where $0<,1 0<<1, x+y<1$

Tags: probability, statistics

I know there are some similar questions but I am having trouble setting up the integral for this problem. I can't decide if it is correct or not to have the integral set up $$\int_0^1\int_0^1kxy\,dy\,dx$$ or
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}kxy\,dy\,dx$$

I am leaning towards the latter because we have that $$x+y<1   \implies   y<1-x$$  but I am not confident. Can somebody please explain which is correct and why. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are correct with your reasoning is that you are integrating over a triangle (plot your bounds). So if you think about the integral written above, we are letting $x$ range from 0 to $1-x$ and y range from 0 to 1, which results in the max at any point being $x+y < 1$. If it helps you visualize, this is equivalent to
$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y} kxy dx dy,$$
where now we are letting $y$ range from 0 to $1-y$ and x range from 0 to 1.

Comment: I have a follow up question. Say I want to find marginal fx(x) for this problem. (sorry I am new to this site and don't know the code)  Would my integral be from [0,1] or [0,1-x] **or** would it depend on which integral I did first in the first part?

Comment: So if you want the marginal of X, then you need to integrate out Y.  So here, because Y depends on X, as in Y goes from 0 to 1-x, you would use that as your bounds. Similarly, if you wanted the marginal of Y, you would integrate out X, where the bounds go from 0 to 1-y. Also, no need to apologize for formatting, we’ve all been there. If you plan on staying in the math/stay field, I highly encourage you to check out LaTex (Tex). Overleaf.com is a user friendly place to start.

Comment: So regardless of how you set up the integral above, you will need to use the bounds of 0 to x+y<1?